# Replace string one by one

Tags: python

I have a string and I need to replace "e" with "x" one at a time. For e.g.

```
x = "three"
```

Then the expected output is:

```
("thrxe", "threx")
```

and if I have 3 characters to replace, for e.g.

```
y = "threee"
```

Then the expected output will be:

```
("thrxee", "threxe", "threex")
```

I have tried this:

```
x.replace("e", "x", 1)  # -> 'thrxe'
```

But not sure how to return the second string **`"threx"`**.

Comment: Do it in a loop, one character at a time.  You don't need `replace` for this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
x = "threee"
# build a generator expression that yields the position of "e"s
# change "e"s with "x" according to location of "e"s yielded from the genexp
[f"{x[:i]}x{x[i+1:]}" for i in (i for i, e in enumerate(x) if e=='e')]
['thrxee', 'threxe', 'threex']
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a generator to replace `e` with `x` sequentially through the string. For example:

```py
def replace(string, old, new):
    l = len(old)
    start = 0
    while start != -1:
        start = string.find(old, start + l)
        if start != -1:
            yield string[:start] + new + string[start + l:]

z = replace('threee', 'e', 'x')
for s in z:
    print(s)
```

Output:

```
thrxee
threxe
threex
```

Note I've generalised the code to allow for arbitrary length match and replacement strings, if you don't need that just replace `l` (`len(old)`) with `1`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def replace(string,old,new):
    f = string.index(old)
    l = list(string)
    i = 0
    for a in range(string.count(old)):
        l[f] = new
        yield ''.join(l)
        l[f]=old
        try:
            f = string.index(old,f+1)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        i+=1


z = replace('threee', 'e', 'x')
for a in z:
    print(a)
```

OUTPUT

```py
thrxee
threxe
threex
```